# Modification of Sound Player on android

Tags: audio, media, playback, assets, piano

i am trying to make a simple piano app. I found this tutorial ;http://www.martinhoeller.net/2012/01/13/developing-a-musical-instrument-app-for-android/ .

I downloaded the file on this link and import it. I run the app and there are 4 buttons on it which plays 4 different notes that are loaded in assets files.

And then i tried to modify this project to make a piano app.

At first i deleted these red buttons from xml.

I added a piano image to background.

And then i created buttons on each key.

The xml file is ;

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/images"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC4"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD4"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonE4"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF4"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG4"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA4"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonB4"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonC5"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD5"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonE5"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then i found notes on internet and download them .

I upload these note files to assets folder.

Each of them is in the wav format.

Then i added these codes to PianoTest Activity ;

```
  buttons = new ArrayList<View>();
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonC4));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonD4));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonF4));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonG4));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonA4));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonB4));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonC5));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonD5));
 buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonE5));
```

And then i modified this function ;

private void toggleButtonSound(View button, boolean down)
{
    String note = null;

```
switch (button.getId())
{
    case R.id.buttonC4:
        note = "C4";
        break;

    case R.id.buttonD4:
        note = "D4";
        break;
    case R.id.buttonE4:
        note = "E4";
        break;

    case R.id.buttonF4:
        note = "F4";
        break;

    case R.id.buttonG4:
        note = "G4";
        break;
    case R.id.buttonA4:
        note = "A4";
        break;

    case R.id.buttonB4:
        note = "B4";
        break;

    case R.id.buttonC5:
        note = "C5";
        break;

    case R.id.buttonD5:
        note = "D5";
        break;
    case R.id.buttonE5:
        note = "E5";
        break;
}
```

Then i changed AudioTrack class . I changed the format to wav file ;

```
public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String path = note + ".wav";
```

Everything else is the same as in the original project.

But the app doesnt work properly.

When i run the app and click one the transparent buttons on a key , it plays a sound but it is not the same sound as it is.

It sounds something different.I can say that an elektronic version of a note.

And when i click some other keys the application crashes . It says the application stopped unexpectedly.

What is wrong ? What should i do to make it work ? The reason can be the files i dpwnloaded. What kind of notes do i need to find ? Is there any special format in terms of their bits or time durations for this project ?

This is very important for me , if you can download the file from the link and run , you can see how it works. You can suggest me the ways to modify it. I hope you can help me.
This is the logcat :

```
05-13 19:49:55.580: D/AndroidRuntime(485): Shutting down VM
05-13 19:49:55.580: W/dalvikvm(485): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.martinhoeller/net.martinhoeller.PianoTestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ButtonView
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ButtonView
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at net.martinhoeller.PianoTestActivity.onCreate(PianoTestActivity.java:23)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  ... 11 more
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.ButtonView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.martinhoeller-1.apk]
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-13 19:49:55.600: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  ... 20 more
05-13 19:52:22.293: D/AndroidRuntime(513): Shutting down VM
05-13 19:52:22.293: W/dalvikvm(513): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at net.martinhoeller.PianoTestActivity.onTouchEvent(PianoTestActivity.java:66)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2089)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-13 19:52:22.309: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: We'll need to see logcat stacktraces for the crashes and the method you use to play the notes at a minimum to help. And any particular reason you're using TextView in your layout instead of the Button view type?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can i add logcat here ?

Comment: I didnt change anything else . The remaining code parts are the same as the original one. In the asset folder there are note files C4.wav , E4. wav etc...

Comment: You are trying to use a class called `ButtonView` and it doesn't exist (or isn't imported correctly) in your project. Are you sure that's the layout that's getting used? Please add the `onCreate()` from your activity.

Comment: NO this happened after i changed every textview to buttonview.

Comment: I will edit in a minute...

Comment: Can it be because of the note files i downloaded ? because there is this code part :
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack.play();

Maybe there should be appropriate files to play ? Is there any need like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a number of issues. Let's try and fix the layout inflate crash first.

```
List<Button> buttons;
...
buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonC4));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonD4));
...
for (Button button : buttons) {
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

That will properly cast your layout's Button Views and set an OnClickListener for each.
Your Activity will need to `implement View.OnClickListener` to use `setOnClickListener(this)`. Replace with the appropriate class if you have your click handling separated, that class will `implement OnClickListener` instead of your Activity in that case.

Comment: Thank you but did you check the link ?

Comment: I had a quick glance at it but I wasn't going to read through the whole thing or try to create a working implementation myself. It's on you to craft your question so that it contains all the info necessary for people to help you without having to spend a lot of time recreating all your code. Clear, concise, complete and direct is the way.

Comment: Actually the original project works and since there are 4 sound files in it i just want to add 3 more and create a simple piano app with 7 notes. The original projects 4 notes are being played but other 3 files i downloaded are not being played properly or never being played sometimes. I just added 3 more files to raw as the original ones. Iam calling them in the project just like the original ones. But these 3 notes dont sound like a note.They are like horn of a car. I am serious. They are being played as something else. I dont know why